# How to properly close a process with NppExec?

Tags: python, notepad++, pywin32, nppexec

I'm not sure what's going on here, but the following code continues running even after I end the process in the NppExec console with Ctrl-C (during the execution of the while loop). I restarted my computer to stop the Ctrl key sends. However, if I run the script in Window's cmd prompt, Ctrl-C ends the script just fine.

```
import time
import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")

time.sleep(2)
while True:
  shell.SendKeys('^') # Ctrl key
  time.sleep(0.5)
```

The NppExec run command I used was: `cmd /C python -u "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

Let me know if there is any more information I can provide. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking here.  Could you clarify?

Comment: @BrooksMoses How can I tweak NppExec so that it acts like a normal console would in the described scenario?

Comment: What happens if you kill the python process? Would that not stop the script?